# Wrap your <Route> in a <Routes> Error but Route is wrapped

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am converting my old code to `react-router-dom` version 6 and I am stuck with this.

This is my code in `react-router-dom` v5:

```
const AddRoute = ({ usergroups, ...props }) => (
  usergroups.length > 0
    ? <Route {...props} />
    : <Route component={NotFound} />
)
```

```
<Switch>
  <AddRoute
    usergroups={userGroups.files}
    exact
    path="/some/path/add"
    render={(props) => (
      <Name {...props} services={services} view={true} />
    )}
  />
</Switch>;
```

and this is how I converted it to version 6:

```
const AddRoute = ({ usergroups, ...props }) => (
  usergroups.length > 0
    ? <Route {...props} /> 
    : <Route element={<NotFound />} />
);
```

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/some/path/add" 
    element={ <AddRoute usergroups={userGroups.metricprofiles} 
      element={<Name services={services} view={true} />} 
      />} 
  />
</Routes>
```

and it didn't work so I tried:

```
<Routes>
  <Route
    path="/some/path/add"
    element={<AddRoute usergroups={userGroups.files} />}
  >
    <Route element={<Name services={services} view={true} />} />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

In both cases I am getting this error `router.js:269 Uncaught Error: A <Route> is only ever to be used as the child of <Routes> element, never rendered directly. Please wrap your <Route> in a <Routes>`. Why is this happening even though I wrapped the code in `<Routes>`?

Can I even use `AddRoute` like I did?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is informing you that the `Route` components that `AddRoute` renders must also be wrapped in a `Routes` component.

```
const AddRoute = ({ usergroups, ...props }) => (
  usergroups.length > 0
    ? <Route {...props} />             // <-- this Route
    : <Route element={<NotFound />} /> // <-- and/or this Route
);
```

Refactor the code to not render these `Route` components and render the content directly.

Example:

```
const AddRoute = ({ element, usergroups }) => usergroups.length > 0
  ? element
  : <NotFound />;
```

This will allow the first routing implementation to work:

```
<Routes>
  <Route
    path="/some/path/add" 
    element={(
      <AddRoute
        usergroups={userGroups.metricprofiles} 
        element={<Name services={services} view />}
      />
    )} 
  />
</Routes>
```

If you prefer the second routing implementation:

```
<Routes>
  <Route element={<AddRoute usergroups={userGroups.files} />}>
    <Route
     path="/some/path/add"
     element={<Name services={services} view />}
   />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

Then `AddRoute` should be rewritten to be a layout route component, e.g. it renders an `Outlet` for the nested route content.

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const AddRoute = ({ usergroups }) => usergroups.length > 0
  ? <Outlet />
  : <NotFound />;
```